# Pocket PC 2003 application with webservice

Tags: web-services, debugging

I am working on a Pocket PC 2003 application that is referencing a Webservice.

I was figuring out ways to debug the Webmethods but not successful.

-I checked the URL property of the Service in WebReferences and made sure it is correct.

-I started debugging the PocketPC application, then built the Webservice as start without debugging, after that went to Debuh> Attach process and attached devenv-"Pocket PC app"

-I also tried attaching to the aspwp.exe process but couldn't seem to hit the break points in Web Methods.

-The webservice is deployed to IIS virtual directory.

-I copy pasted the entire webservice folder in the virtual directory. Then I am opening the solution file in Visual Studio. Start without debugging, when the webmethods show in browser, click on it, then click Invoke

Can someone guide me the proper way to debug a Webservice of this type? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think there was connectivity problem because I was using the PocketPC2003 simulator in VS-2005. Today I actually connect the mobile device. Connected a ethernet cable to it and tried calling the webservice. It worked fine. Now, I am trying to figure out the correct way to hit the break points.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Visual Studio 2005 or higher, instead of IIS, use the toy Web service that comes with Visual Studio. In the properties of your ASP.NET project with the Web services, under "Web", check the "Use Visual Stuidio Development server". In order to make the toy server start, you have so start the ASP.NET project from Visual Studio.

Then you attach to the process called Webdev.Webserver.exe using Managed code debugging.